# How to add right-mouse click listener on a TreeViewer (JFace) item?

Tags: java, treeview, jface

I don't know how to add right-mouse click listener on a TreeViewer (JFace) item?

This is my source I create a class treeview extends from viewpart :

```
/* 
 * Creates the tree.
 * 
 * @return the tree object and create part control
 */
private TreeObject CreateTree() {
    TreeParent root = new TreeParent("");

    DemoTreeModel ctModel = new DemoTreeModel();
    List<String> listType = ctModel.getType();
    for (String type : listType) {
        TreeParent parentNode1 = new TreeParent(type);
        parentNode1.setLevel(1);

        List<String> listMachine = ctModel.getName(type);
        if (listMachine != null) {
            for (String machine : listMachine) {
                TreeParent childNode1 = new TreeParent(machine);
                childNode1.setLevel(2);
                parentNode1.addChild(childNode1);
                List<String> listVersion = ctModel.getVersion(machine);

                if (listVersion != null) {
                    for (String ver : listVersion) {
                        TreeObject version = new TreeObject(ver);
                        version.setLevel(3);
                        version.setData(ver);
                        childNode1.addChild(version);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        root.addChild(parentNode1);
    }

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager();
menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
    @Override
    public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager menuManager) {
        ... add items to menu manager
    }
});

Control tree = treeViewer.getControl();

Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(tree);

tree.setMenu(menu);
```

This is using an `IMenuListener` which lets you add different menu items each time the menu is displayed, so you can adapt to what is selected.

Comment: Let me try it, Thank you so much !